# PDF.js is displayed unproperly in google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, pdf.js

My application generates a pdf file which is displayed to a user via PDF.js installed as extension on google-chrome and firefox. Although, google-chrome  shows the pdf file, but for some reason, a toolbar of PDF.js (that holds zoom in/out, previous/next and other options) is missing. PDF.js works without problems on firefox. I removed all my extensions from google-chrome, thinking that one of them is blocking pdf.js but that did not help. Google-chrome gives the same result on oth Linux(64 bit) and Windows(64-bit). Any comments/suggestions how to fix that are highly appreciated!

Comment: The official [PDF.js Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) or some custom one? In any case can you provide a link to a page that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @RobW Yes, the official extension. I am still working on my app so unfortunately, it is not available online yet. Thanks

Comment: Could you create a reduced test case that demonstrates the issue, or share a link by mail with me? I can publish an update to the Chrome extension if necessary to resolve the problem.